# Ipyparallel ssh cluster creates/connects, but does not return workers

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-parallel

I'm trying to setup the `ipyparallel` cluster over ssh with the following settings specified in the `~/.ipython/profile_ssh/ipcluster_config.py`:

```
c.IPClusterEngines.engine_launcher_class = 'SSH'
c.IPClusterStart.controller_launcher_class = 'LocalControllerLauncher'
c.SSHControllerLauncher.controller_args = ['--reuse', '--ip=*']
c.SSHEngineSetLauncher.engines = {'<hostname-of-the-cluster>': 1,}
```

This seems to start as expected, creates the remote profiles, and I am able to connect, however I get no workers:

```
In [1]: import ipyparallel as ipp

In [2]: c = ipp.Client(profile='ssh')

In [3]: c
Out[3]: <ipyparallel.client.client.Client at 0x7fb9c0f96f98>

In [4]: c.ids
Out[4]: []
```

All pythons are setup from conda-forge and up to date. Any ideas what could be wrong? Increasing the number of engines on the host does not change the situation.

Comment: I played with ssh and ipyparallel and it seems that ssh is not able to connect to itself.